# Need help with finding Dirichlet generating function

Tags: number-theory, generating-functions, dirichlet-series, mobius-function

I am unable to find the following generating function:
$$\tag{1}{\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{2^{-k_n} \mu \big(\frac{n}{2^{k_n}}\big)}{n^s}}$$

$\mu$ is Möbius function, $k_n$ is the highest integer number so that $2^{k_n}$ divides $n$ (maybe someone is more familiar with notation $2^{k_n}\mid\mid n$).

I am able to find generating functions of $\mu \big(\frac{n}{2^{k_n}}\big)$ and $2^{-k_n}$ separately:
$${\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\mu \big(\frac{n}{2^{k_n}}\big)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\left(1-2^{-s}\right)^2 \zeta (s)}}$$
$${\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{2^{-k_n}}{n^s}=\frac{\left(2^s-1\right) \zeta (s)}{2^s-\frac{1}{2}}}$$

Then I tried to use the formula in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4476852/400836), that relates term-wise product of arithmetic functions with its generating function, but I could not simplify the integral.

Any ideas how to find the generating function of $(1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $n=mk_n$ where $m$ is odd,
\begin{align*}
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{2^{-k_n} \mu \big(\frac{n}{2^{k_n}}\big)}{n^s}
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{\substack{n\ge1 \\ k_n = k}} \frac{2^{-k_n} \mu \big(\frac{n}{2^{k_n}}\big)}{n^s} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k} \sum_{\substack{m\ge1 \\ m\text{ odd}}} \frac{\mu(m)}{(2^km)^s} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k(s+1)} \sum_{\substack{m\ge1 \\ m\text{ odd}}} \frac{\mu(m)}{m^s} = \frac1{1-2^{-s-1}} \frac1{\zeta(s)}(1-2^{-s})^{-1}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you. I believe it should be $\frac{1}{\left(1-2^{-s-1}\right) \left(1-2^{-s}\right) \zeta (s)}$.